# Is blender a software used in metaverse?

Tags: modeling

I'm a Graphic and UI/UX Designer and I would like to start designing for the Metaverse. I would like to know if Blender is a software used in 3D modeling for Metaverse. If it isn't, could you advise me in which softwares are the most used?

Comment: Depends on what you need from it. It's an all-round 3D package capable of modelling, sculpting, animation and rendering. Its applications include motion graphics, CGI, VFX, video games, movies, VR and more. So yes, it will probably find use when the 'metaverse' materialises too, but like Alexandre said, it's all speculation at this point.

Comment: it looks like it's the new word for Second Life, no?

Comment: @moonboots no.  The 'verse is supposed to be composed of virtual words that are decentralized (in the networking sense) and under control of differing adminstrative agencies.  Of course, that meaning will probably change.

Comment: Perhaps, but a lot of money is being spent by large companies, including Apple, Facebook, Google and Samsung to make it happen.  More likely what emerges will be different than what people envision from reading Sci-Fi and so will probably renamed; but the idea of visual navigation in AR/VR isn't going to go away.

Comment: @MartyFouts The [“corporate dystopia”-type theme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snow_Crash#Metaverse) seems to be holding up well so far.

Comment: @AlexandreMarcati It seems to me that the difference between self-driving cars and what's missing from the net to achieve the 'metaverse' is akin to the difference between brain transplanting and finding the right tweezers to remove a  sliver.  The concepts for the metaverse date back to ARPA experiments in the 1960s. What has been missing, from a technology standpoint, is inexpensive virtual/augmented reality interfaces and sufficient inexpensive network bandwidth.  Both of those are inevitable.

Comment: I have never used blender but I know that blender supports import and export of USD(universal scene description) which is a platform for interchange of data between metaworld and 3d applications.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[*Metaverse*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaverse) is Yet Another Marketing Jargon (YAMJ) that has no agreed meaning; although Wikipedia simplifies the definition to

> a network of 3D virtual worlds focused on social connection.

The Metaverse, under that definition, does already exist, and is growing.  Samsung, for example, has a collaboration with Decentralland that has placed 800 or so Samsung virtual stores in the 'verse.

Since one of the aspects of the Metaverse is [Augmented Reality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Augmented_reality) (AR) and there are people using Blender to develop AR specifically for the metaverse, then yes, by example, Blender is a tool that is and will be used in the Metaverse.  At least until the marketing people move on to another term to describe the online social experience.

In general, expect that Blender will become increasingly more common in any 3D environment building, whatever it is called.

Comment: ... Third Life... Fourth Life ... Fifth Life,,,,

Comment: Whenever someone mentions the metaverse I think of Geocities and end up giggling.